# Fable/Thoth compile error: toJson is not defined

Tags: post, fetch, fable-f#

I am trying to do a POST request with Fable, following this tutorial: https://fable.io/fable-powerpack/posts/fetch.html

I am getting this compile error:

```
error FSHARP: The value or constructor 'toJson' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:
       JSON (code 39)
     @ ./UI/UI.fsproj 1:0-24 1:0-24
```

Here is my code:

```
let submitForm = 
    let txtName = getInputElementById("txtName")
    let postData = { Name = txtName.value }

    let requestProps =
        [ RequestProperties.Method HttpMethod.POST
        ; requestHeaders [ContentType "application/json"]
        ; RequestProperties.Body (unbox (toJson postData))
        ]
        //Encode.Auto.toString(1, postData)
        //toJson    
        //Fable.Core.JS.JSON.stringify

    promise {
        let! response = fetch "http://localhost:5000/employee/create" requestProps
        let responseText = response.text()
        Browser.console.log responseText
    } |> ignore
```

I also get these compile errors in Fable/.fable/Thoth.Json.2.0.0/Encode.fs:

```
The value, constructor, namespace or type 'Array' is not defined. (code 39)
The value, constructor, namespace or type 'JSON' is not defined.
```

I am guessing this is because Fable is referencing Thoth 2.0.0, instead of the latest version. How can I fix this error?

https://github.com/jaydpather/FunctionalCrudForms/blob/master/Fable/UI/UI.fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disclaimer I am the maintainer of Thoth.Json.

It seems like you are using a 2+ year-old version of Fable.

fable-powerpack has been deprecated and has been split into different packages. But it seems like we forgot to update this website.

In the case of the Fetch API, it is now inside the package Fable.Fetch.

`toJson` doesn't exist anymore it is recommended to use [Thoth.Json](https://thoth-org.github.io//Thoth.Json/) or [Fable.SimpleJson](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Fable.SimpleJson)

There is also the package [Thoth.Fetch](https://thoth-org.github.io//Thoth.Fetch/) which already glue together Fetch and Thoth.Json so you don't have to write the (de)serialization part.

In your case, it would give something like that:

```
let createBook () : JS.Promise<unit> =
    promise {
        let url = "http://localhost:5000/employee/create"
        let txtName = getInputElementById("txtName")
        let data =
            {| Name = = txtName .Value |} // Using an anonymous for simplicity

        return! Fetch.post(url, data, caseStrategy = CamelCase)
    }
```

Comment: Hi Maxime, thanks for your answer. Fable is an awesome API, but it would really help if you had a complete example app.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the kind word :)

We have several applications which can serve as an example. For example, fulma-demo is Q&A application which showcase usage of Elmish, Thoth.Json, Fetch https://github.com/MangelMaxime/fulma-demo/

There is also "The Elmish book" which goes step by step from basic Fable example to complex Elmish application with exercise: https://zaid-ajaj.github.io/the-elmish-book/

Fable Awesome could help find more resources too: https://github.com/kunjee17/awesome-fable

But indeed, documentation is still rough it takes a lot of time to improve. Hope, it helps